# Change Action Bar Title using a string for Android

Tags: java, android

I want to change the Action Bar title in the .java file depending on which cell is tapped. When the new activity is called here, I am only able to change the action bar title through the xml file, but I want to use a string from my previous activity (in order to change the action bar title to whatever the cell title was in the previous activity).

In this case the String would be sText

```
public class ListViewAndroidExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_view_android_example, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_android_example);

        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_android_example);

            ListView mlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            mlistView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    new String[] {"#unlv", "#unr", "#ucla", "#usc"}));

            mlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text Game, Help, Home
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String sText = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(ListViewAndroidExample.this, ChatRoom.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //else if(sText.equals("Help")) ..........

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Created by Jason on 6/30/2014.
     */
    public static class ChatRoom extends Activity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.chatlayout);

            this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try

```
getActionBar().setTitle(sText);
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(sText);
```

Comment: Yea. The only issue is I get cannot resolve the symbol... Guess I have no clue where to put that.

Comment: put it in `onCreate()`. Or if you're using ` startActivityForResult()` then try putting it in `onActivityResult`. More info on `startActivityForResult`: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html